# Does Mark 10:6 imply a short (literal) creation week?

Tags: genesis, jesus, mark, creation, age

In speaking about marriage and divorce, Jesus takes the Pharisees back to the beginning in Mark 10:6 (NKJV, emphasis mine):

> "But from **the beginning of the creation [αρχης κτισεως]**, God ‘made them male and female.’"

The Greek phrase **αρχης κτισεως** appears in two other passages of Scripture (NKJV, emphasis mine):

> "For in those days there will be tribulation, such as has not been since **the beginning of the creation [αρχης κτισεως]** which God created until this time, nor ever shall be." (Matt. 13:19)

> and saying, "Where is the promise of His coming? For since the fathers fell asleep, all things continue as they were from **the beginning of creation [αρχης κτισεως]**." (2 Pet. 3:4)

In Mark 10:6, does "the beginning of the creation" refer to the creation of the Universe? If so, does Jesus' placing of the creation at "the beginning" suggest that humankind was created during the beginning of the Universe? To explain, within the interpretive framework of a literal week, Day 6 (or any day for that matter) could easily be called "the beginning of the creation." However, if the days involved ages of time, Day 6 (when mankind was created, Gen. 1:26-31) would seem to be many ages **after** "the beginning of the creation," placing the day more toward recent times.

Does Jesus' language, therefore, imply a short, literal creation week in which even Day 6 happened toward "the beginning of the creation"?

**Note:** In keeping with the policy of the Hermenutics Stack Exchange, this question is not about whether the earth is old or young; I'm not even asking whether the Bible teaches that the earth is old or young. Instead, I'm asking if Mark 10:6 in particular implies a literal creation week with its quotation from Genesis 1:27 (which, in context, is Day 6), a verse Jesus says happened at "the beginning of the creation" (NKJV).

Comment: Up-voted +1 and answered. No doubt about it. Excellent question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP's question is quite specific - does Mark 10:6 imply a six-day creation?

Answer - no it does not - a six day creation is not mentioned, so it is neither confirmed nor denied.

What is confirmed is the following:

- God created all things
- man and woman were created near the beginning of the creation of the world
- Mankind was created in a sexually binary form - male and female.

That is all.

The closest we get to creation in six days is Heb 4:4, but only obliquely:

> For somewhere He has spoken about the seventh day in this manner: “And
> on the seventh day God rested from all His works.”

In fact, the NT never mentions six days of creation week anywhere.  However, we do have one more allusion to creation week but it is quite indirect:

> Rev 14:7 - Worship the One who made the heavens and the earth and the
> sea and the springs of waters.”

This appears to be an allusion to the fourth commandment in Ex 20:11 -

> **For in six days the LORD made the heavens and the earth and the sea** and all that is in them, but on the seventh day He rested.
> Therefore the LORD blessed the Sabbath day and set it apart as holy.

Again, this is an indirect allusion - there is no direct allusion to six-day creation in the NT.

Matt 19:4 quotes Gen 1:27 about the creation on the sixth day; and  Matt 19:5 quotes Gen 2:24, but again, this is quite indirect.  Despite this, it does confirm Jesus' belief in the veracity and literal nature of the Genesis creation record.

**APPENDIX - Six days of creation**

While the NT never mentions six days of creation, there are plenty of OT texts that do:

- Gen 1 - the original record of six days of creation
- Ex 20:11 - seventh day Sabbath is the memorial of creation in six days
- Ex 31:15 - essentially the same as Ex 20:11
- Ex 16:26 - Sabbath command repeated about manna
- Ex 23:12 - ditto
- Ex 34:21 - ditto
- Lev 23:3 - ditto
- Deut 5:13 - ditto

Comment: There is also mention of Adam in the NT, which confirms not only was mankind created in binary form, but there was a first man.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, like the genealogy of Jesus in Luke 3. "... son of Adam, son of God"

Comment: Don't forget also, that [2 Peter 3:5-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Peter+3&version=ESV) references the literal flood, saying people in the last days will deny Creation and the Flood. *"For they deliberately overlook this fact, that the heavens existed long ago, and the earth was formed out of water and through water by the word of God, 6 and that by means of these the world that then existed was deluged with water and perished."* (ESV)

Comment: Great post! I'm likely going to mark this as the accepted answer, though I'm going to give Hold To The Rod a chance to respond to a question I asked on his answer.

Comment: "man and woman were created near the beginning of the creation of the world" "Near" the beginning, or "from the beginning?"

Comment: @SolaGratia - On the sixth day is "at the beginning of the creation of the world but near the beginning.  God created "male and female" from the very beginning of the creation of humans.  But I did not want to get into these technicalities.

Comment: @Dottard Jesus doesn't say "from the beginning *of the creation of humans*." He counts "*the beginning*" as all that was included in "in *the beginning God* created the heavens and the earth," and Genesis lays out that this occurred on seven days. The seven days are, as a whole, "the beginning," per the narrative of Genesis. Genesis 1:1 is a chapter heading describing what the following narrative is and exists to describe. The creation of humans is not 'near' the beginning, it's part of that seven day Beginning which Genesis' early chapters literally exist to speak of.

Comment: @SolaGratia - If you place it in that light I completely agree.

Comment: @SolaGratia Well put. And each day, one at a time, "with evening and morning".

Answer (score 2):

**Does "the creation" refer to the creation of the Universe?**

---

*de arches ktisews* undoubtedly means 'from beginning of creation'. It can mean nothing else.

Had Jesus of Nazareth meant to infer 'the beginning of the creation of humanity' he would have, necessarily, added some more vocabulary or grammar.

That 'creation' lacks an article indicates that Jesus is expressing the concept of creation, as such. The absolute concept 'creation' means, unavoidably, all creation. The creation of all things.

Thus Jesus of Nazareth, in these words, places the creation of humanity at the beginning of creation, and the 'foundational' beginning at that, as the word *arche* has a depth and breadth of meaning that implies a substantial, foundational statis resulting in other processes following on from that foundational event or appointment.

---

[Thayer (Biblehub) :](https://biblehub.com/greek/746.htm)

**1 Beginning, origin**

a) ἀρχή used absolutely, of the beginning of all things: ... Mark 10:6 ...

Comment: While I agree with the content of this answer I'm not sure it addresses the question about "short creation week" or young-earth hypothesis. For example, Jesus is human and was present *in the beginning*, (see 1 John 1:1), a point that's compatible with both interpretations.

Comment: @OmarL do you mean that Jesus -as a human- was present in the beginning? Jesus -as a human- appeared on his birth about ~2,000 years ago.

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete, that is exactly what I meant, but now I'm not so sure. I've heard the phrase "He took on flesh". But I'm not sure that means "became human". Now He's in Heaven, still in human form (this is why He saves humans and not some other fallen race). The more I think about it the more I'm getting a bit confused about it.

Comment: @OmarL That '_the word became flesh and dwelt among us_' (John 1:14) clearly relates to the incarnation of Jesus Christ being born of Mary in Bethlehem. Prior to that, the Son of God is spoken of as 'the word' which was 'in the beginning' (John 1:1).

Comment: @NigelJ Yes, of course, but "incarnation" is not the same as "become human". Otherwise our souls and spirits would not be human. But we're getting off track a little here; I just wanted to point you to the question: "does Mark 10:6 imply short creation week", which I don't think your post answers

Comment: @OmarL I specifically answered _Does "the creation" refer to the creation of the Universe?_ and I have edited to make that clearer. Also, I cannot see how 'incarnation' and 'become human' can possibly mean different things, myself. There is a genuine difference between 'manifestation' (as in, for example, the appearance in the burning fiery furnace witnessed by Nebuchadnezzar) and 'incarnation', but that is a different matter.

Comment: Exactly therein is the difference. The figure in the furnace was human (Daniel 3:5), but did not have human flesh (otherwise the body would've burned up and be killed). That's different from Jesus on the cross: in that case the body *was* killed. So incarnation means mortality, but being human does not mean being mortal (Rev. 1:18, also Rev 21:4)

Comment: It's possible I'm wrong about this

Comment: @OmarL No. The 'body was killed' is incorrect. Jesus made it clear aforehand that none could take his life : he offered it, voluntarily. 'No man taketh it from me' John 10:18. And no, the manifestation/human flesh - the other three were human flesh and were not burned up. Thus this does not prove that the fourth was not _human flesh in  manifestation_.

Comment: @OmarL There were three others who did have human flesh and were unscathed within the fiery furnace.

Comment: As I recall, that's because they were under protection from the one who looked like God's son.#

Comment: @OmarL Philippians 2:7 states that Jesus took the form of a servant, made in the likeness of men. Why 'took the form' if it was already human?

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete Do you think that to be human is the same as having a mortal, fallen body? (do we cease to be human when we die, and our spirits leave the body?) I don't think so. Therefore I'm not sure that incarnation has to be the moment that Jesus became human.

Comment: @OmarL No, you don't stop being human in that scenario, but to start being a human you absolutely need a flesh body.

Comment: Also, the human race is a _creation_ of God, and Jesus is definitely not a creation.

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete Your position raises more questions than it answers, for example a) Does scripture actually say that? b) does this mean Jesus is not human to begin with? c) could some other spiritual being, Lucifer for example, take on flesh in the same way Jesus did? d) Could Jesus have taken on another kind of body, to redeem another race? e) What does "God the Father" mean?

Comment: "Also, the human race is a creation of God, and Jesus is definitely not a creation", ah, that's more convincing. I'll think about that some more. It's probable I'll have some more questions about this later. Is hermeneutics.stackexchange the right place?

Comment: @OmarL If your question is about the _meaning_ of Scripture, then yes; if not, maybe the scope will fit better on christianity.stackexchange!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135047/discussion-between-ivan-garcia-topete-and-omarl).

Answer (score 1):

The passage does not take a position on this issue. Jesus speaks of the beginning of creation, but does not specify the beginning of the creation of *what*. The creation of the universe? Life on earth? Humans?

The Greek word in Mark, as well as in the parallel passage in Matthew, is ἀρχή, meaning beginning or origin (it can also be used figuratively to mean the "foremost") ([source](https://biblehub.com/greek/746.htm)). It need not refer to an absolute beginning.

Additional detail is provided by Matthew in the same context:

> He saith unto them, Moses because of the hardness of your hearts
> suffered you to put away your wives: but from the **beginning** it was
> not so (Matthew 19:8)

This suggests the context is the beginning of humanity or, more precisely, the beginning of marriage. The message here is that marriage between man & woman--and its importance--is not something that was invented or contrived partway through the human experience--it is an original and fundamental part of what God created.

Jesus compares and contrasts the practices of marriage in His day & in Moses' day, with the way God set it up in the beginning. Absent any reason to believe that galaxies/stars/planets were getting married & divorced, the beginning this passage has in mind is the family of Adam & Eve.

Comment: Great answer. +1 :)

Comment: This focuses on the word "beginning", however, Mark 10:6 contains both that word AND "creation". The word for creation ["ktisis"](https://biblehub.com/greek/2937.htm) refers to  creation *ex nihilo*, out of nothing. Mankind was not made of nothing, but of the dust God had already created. So I'd say this answer is a bit lacking in addressing that

Comment: @mbomb007 while I agree mankind was not made out of nothing, I respectfully disagree that ktisis necessarily means creation out of nothing. It can also mean to form or to mold (implying there is existing material)

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Do you have evidence to support your disagreement? The concordances of the Bible say that that word has been used explicitly to mean creation ex nihilo since Homer's time prior to the writing of the New Testament, meaning that the standard usage of the term at the time this part of the Bible was written meant creation out of nothing.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod While "beginning" is broad by itself, would "beginning of the creation" refer specifically to the beginning of the Universe? Compare Mark 13:19; Ephesians 3:9; 2 Peter 3:4. What are your thoughts? :)

Comment: @mbomb007 sure thing. My argument is not that it cannot mean creation out of nothing, but that it doesn't necessarily mean that. For example, it's used in 2 Cor 5:17 & Gal 6:15 to refer to things created out of something else. κτίσις comes from the verb κτίζω, which Strong's concordance defines as "create, form, shape, make". This verb is used in, e.g. Eph 2:15 & 4:24, 1 Cor 11:9, Matt 19:4 to refer to creating something out of things which already exist.

Comment: I submit that there is no unambiguous usage of κτίζω to mean "creation out of nothing" in the New Testament, which is why the early Christian writers who supported creation ex-nihilo used 2 Maccabees, not the New Testament, as a proof text.

Comment: @TheEditor thanks for the question. My thoughts are presented in the 1st paragraph of my answer--the beginning of the creation *of what*? Could be the universe. Or the earth (as in Eph 2:15, which gratefully is explicit). Or humanity. Genesis breaks creation into segments, each of which have a similar beginning and end. Similar language could describe the beginning of the fallen world, Israel, the Mosaic law, etc. I believe Matt. 19:8 provides good contextual reason to believe this teaching is about Adam & Eve, not the universe; I find Mark 10:6 neither favors nor opposes the view in the OP.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Thank you for that explanation. I looked at Matthew 19:8, which you referenced, and it says "from the beginning" (NKJV) while Mark 10:6 is more specific/informative, "from the beginning **of the creation**" (NKJV, emphasis mine). Instead of interpreting the specific (Mark 10:6) in light of the general (Matt. 19:8), should we understand the general ("from the beginning," Matt. 19:8) in light of the more informative, specific phrase ("from the beginning of the creation")? Everywhere else, I'm not sure "the beginning of creation" clearly references anything but the world/Universe.